# How do I fix a timer that doesn't want to start?

Tags: c++

I made this timer a few days ago and today and decided to mess around with it. I wanted it to be able to stop whenever I type in "stop" but I think I did something wrong and now the timer doesn't start at all. What's the reason for this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    int hr=0, min=0, sec=0;
    std::string x;
    while(true){
        system("clear");
        std::cout << hr << " : " << min << " : " << sec << std::endl;
        sec++;
        if(sec==60){
            min++;
            sec=0;
            if(min==60){
                hr++;
                min=0;
                if(hr==1){
                    hr=0;
                }
            }
        }
        sleep(1);
        std::cin >> x;
        if (x == "stop")
        {
            break;
        }
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::cin >> x;` blocks your program's execution until you input something.  If you want your timer to be running in the background then you _could_ put it in a thread but I think that's too advanced for you right now.  And besides, `sleep` is super inaccurate for timing.  What you should do is just call `time()` to get the epoch time once.  When you stop, call it again and subtract the first.  You then have the elapsed seconds.  It's simple to then derive the hours, minutes and seconds from that value with basic division and modulo.  Or in C++, consider `<chrono>` from the standard library.

Comment: Hmm, I lambasted another person for posting an answer using threading, but actually on closer reading of your question that seems to be what is required if you want to be actually _displaying_ a timer that ticks away while waiting for input.  It is actually quite a subtle art doing this safely.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple fix for that, see you added std::cin>>x;
But, cin pauses the further execution for reading the input...

That means there are two fix(s) -

1. include conio.h
   Then change the data type of x to char (String - > char)
   Then change the statement after `sleep(1);` to `if(kbhit()) {x = getch();}`
   Then change `if (x == "stop")` to `if (x == 's' || x == 'S')`
   It should work!
   Final code -

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    
    int main(){
        int hr=0, min=0, sec=0;
        char x;
        while(true){
            system("clear");
            std::cout << hr << " : " << min << " : " << sec << 
 std::endl;
            sec++;
            if(sec==60){
                min++;
                sec=0;
                if(min==60){
                    hr++;
                    min=0;
                    if(hr==1){
                        hr=0;
                    }
                 }
            }
            sleep(1);
            if (kbhit())
            x = getch();
            if (x == 's' || x == 'S')
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

2. include conio.h
   Then change the statement after `sleep(1);` to `if(kbhit()) {std::cin>>x;}`
   It should work!
   Final code -

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <conio.h>

    int main(){
        int hr=0, min=0, sec=0;
        char x;
        while(true){
            system("clear");
            std::cout << hr << " : " << min << " : " << sec << std::endl;
            sec++;
            if(sec==60){
                min++;
                sec=0;
                if(min==60){
                    hr++;
                    min=0;
                    if(hr==1){
                        hr=0;
                    }
                }
            }
            sleep(1);
            if (kbhit())
            std::cin>>x;
            if (x == "stop")
            {
                 break;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

The first method will stop the timer as soon as you press 's' but, second method will stop the timer while you are typing but if it doesn't equal to stop then it will resume the timer again...

This is my first time answering so idk if code block works.